# Load Excel Range into VB DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

New to VB. I'm trying to convert 8000 lines of VBA Macros to VB. I'm just starting and I'm sure I'll be asking for a lot of help here.

I am trying to load an Excel Range into a DataGridView. The DataGridView is staying blank after I add the array as a datasource. What am I missing?

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Dropbox\Test\Test.xls")
    xlWorkSheet = xlApp.Sheets("TestPage")
    Dim loadArray(,) As Object = xlWorkSheet.Range("B15:N22").Value
    DataGridView1.DataSource = loadArray
    xlApp.Visible = False
    xlApp.Quit()
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `DataGridView1.DataSource = loadArray`, I would try this. It will create a column in the datagridview for "B-N", and will fill the datagridview's rows with the cell values from the spreadsheet (assuming the loadarray loaded the data correctly).

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 12  '0 = B to 12 = N
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), i.ToString())
    For j As Integer = 0 To 6
        If i = 0 Then
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        End If
        dataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value = loadArray(i,j)
    Next
Next
```

HTH